# repeat same raster layer to create a raster stack

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to create a raster stack from a rasterlayer, where the raster stack is just the same raster layer repeated a certain number of times.

I can do something like this:

```
library(raster)
rasterstack <- addLayer(rasterlayer, rasterLayer, rasterLayer)
```

and this works. However, i want the stack to be about a 1000 layers. I guess i could just loop through, but i was wondering if there was a more sophisticated way to doing this.

The reason I am trying to do this is to calculate the weighted mean of a raster stack with data where each layer is a different time period, and where the weights are in a different raster layer object. I am hoping that if I create a rasterstack from the weights raster  layer with the same number of layers as the data, I'll be able to do something like:

```
  weightedmean <- weighted.mean( data.RasterStack, weights.RasterStack )
```

Comment: Are the weights spatially variable? if not, you can simply provide a vector of weights (one number for each layer in the data.RasterStack) instead of a raster stack to the weighted.mean function.

Comment: Yes, the weights are spatially variable (different for each grid cell), but are the same for each layer.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041499/stacking-an-existing-rasterstack-multiple-times/21041582?noredirect=1#comment31634090_21041582) recent post of mine. @SimonO'Hanlon provided an excellent answer!

Answer (score 7):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=1:100)
```

Solution

```
n <- 10  # number of copies
s <- stack(lapply(1:n, function(i) r))
```

Or

```
s <- stack(replicate(n, r))
```