# Combining raster stacks

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have multiple raster stacks containing temperature data from CRU TS 3.23

I have read in the files as follows:

```
nc = stack("cru_ts3.23.1951.1960.pre.dat.nc", varname = "pre")
nc2 = stack("cru_ts3.23.1961.1970.pre.dat.nc", varname = "pre")
...
nc7 = stack("cru_ts3.23.2011.2014.pre.dat.nc", varname = "pre")
```

Is there any way I can combine all these rasters to create one big one? I am looking at precipitation trends, so much easier to do when they're all in one object! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`raster::stack(nc, nc2, nc3, nc4, nc5, nc6, nc7)` should do the trick. A very similar approach has been described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041499/stacking-an-existing-rasterstack-multiple-times).

However, be aware that the objects you would like to `stack` are required to have an identical coordinate references system (`CRS`), resolution (`res`), and `extent`. Otherwise, `stack` will most likely fail. You could deploy `raster::projectRaster` and `raster::resample` to create objects with uniform spatial properties if one (or several) of the above criteria is different.

Comment: You can also do the stacking in one line, using: `stack("cru_ts3.23.1951.1960.pre.dat.nc","cru_ts3.23.1951.1970.pre.dat.nc","cru_ts3.23.1951.2014.pre.dat.nc", varname = "pre")`

Comment: True story @maRtin, I just wanted to stick with the above created objects.